# Cannot get player to move in 2D Platformer

Tags: javascript, html, math, 2d, physics

I'm trying to create a 2D platformer in JavaScript, I'm getting no errors, but it's not working properly. Pressing the left arrow or the up arrow key does nothing, pressing the right arrow key causes the X-Pos to start incrementing by 1 pixel per tick. I realize this code is long and my 'physics' logic is completely twisted and backwards, but I can't understand anyone's guides on how to add phsyics and velocity and acceleration and gravity and I'm just super confused. I started using JavaScript a week ago and I really have no idea what I'm doing, so any recommendations about any of my code, even things that aren't technically 'problems' would be most appreciated. Thanks guys, you're dope <3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <head>
    <title>For The Intended</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="800"></canvas>
  <!-- <script src="platform.js"></script> -->
  <script>



    //
    //notes
    //



    //Block collision should come when velocity tries to move, and the x-y position should be player.x + player.velocity to check exactly where the collision will be



    //
    //
    //
    //
    //
    //
    //Canvas Settings
    var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
    cvs.style = "position:absolute; left: 60%; width: 1200; margin-left: -800px";

    //Variables
    var platforms = [];
    var imgCount = 0
    var totalImgCount = 3
    var lastUpdate = Date.now();
    var keys = {};

    //Controls


    //Images
    var platformImage = new Image();
    var playerImage = new Image();
    var bgImage = new Image();
    platformImage.src = "images/platform.png";
    playerImage.src = "images/forward1.png";
    playerImage.src = "images/backward1.png";
    bgImage.src = "images/bg.png";
    platformImage.onload = function() { 
       imgCount += 1
     }
    playerImage.onload = function() { 
       imgCount += 1
     }
    bgImage.onload = function() { 
       imgCount += 1
     }

     //Objects

     //Platforms
    function Platform(x, y, length, height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.length = length;
        this.height = height;
        platforms.push(this)

    }

    platform = new Platform(30,30,30,30)
    platform = new Platform(40,40,40,40)

    //Player
    function Player(x, y, gravity, velocityX, velocityY, acceleration, isJumping, direction){
      this.x = x
      this.y = y
      this.gravity = gravity
      this.velocityX = velocityX
      this.velocityY = velocityY
      this.acceleration = acceleration
      this.isJumping = isJumping
      this.direction = direction

    }
      player = new Player(200, 600, 0.7, 1, 1, false, "forward")
      function jump() {
          if (player.isJumping == false) {
              player.velocityY = -15;
              player.isJumping = true;
          }
      }
      function jumpingHandler() {
         if (player.isJumping) {
            player.velocityY += player.gravity;
             player.y += player.velocityY;
            draw();
               if (player.y > 600) {
                   player.y = 600;
                   player.velocityY = 0;
                   player.isJumping = false;

                 }
           }
      }

  *function move(e) {
    if(keys[e.keyCode]) {
        if(keys[38]) {
          jump();
      }
      if(keys[37]) {
        if (player.x > 150){
          if (player.acceleration > -5){
            player.acceleration = Math.floor(player.acceleration);
            player.acceleratoion -= 1
            player.acceleration = Math.floor(player.acceleration);
          }
          player.direction = "backward"
          playerImage.src = "images/backward1.png";

        }
      }
      if(keys[39]) {
        if (player.x < 1050){
          console.log("hey")
          if (player.acceleration < 5){
            console.log("hey2")
            player.acceleration = Math.floor(player.acceleration);
            player.acceleration += 1
            player.acceleration = Math.floor(player.acceleration);
          }
          player.direction = "forward"
          playerImage.src = "images/forward1.png";
        }

      }
    }
  }*
    //Game Requirements

    function draw() {
      if (imgCount == 3) {
        for (var i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
           ctx.drawImage(platformImage, platforms[i].x, platforms[i].y)
              //Do something
        }
        ctx.drawImage(playerImage, player.x, player.y)
      }
    }
    setInterval(update, 33);
    function updateKeys() {
      window.onkeyup = function(e) { keys[e.keyCode] = false; move(e)}
      window.onkeydown = function(e) { keys[e.keyCode] = true; move(e)}
    }
    function update() {

      if (player.acceleration > 1) {player.acceleration -= 0.2}
      if (player.acceleration < 1) {player.acceleration += 0.2}
      player.acceleration = Math.floor(player.acceleration);
      player.velocityX = player.acceleration
      player.x += (player.velocityX)
      console.log("Velocity" + player.velocityX)
      console.log("Acceleration" + player.acceleration)
      console.log("X-Pos" + player.x)
      jumpingHandler()
      updateKeys()
      draw()
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you only just started using JavaScript a week ago, you may want to start out with some simpler projects before trying to implement a physics engine.

Comment: You're probably right but my sister wants the game soon :/ It's a promotional game for her book and I need to get it out ASAP.

Comment: If that's the case, she should probably hire somebody to do this for her. That being said, one thing I notice is you're re-declaring your keyup/keydown listener (in `updateKeys()`) every time `update` is called. You should only do that once, at the start of your program. Also, you should do your event listener on the document, not the window (like how it's described in the example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)).